# Angular HTTP Interceptors at Module Level

Tags: javascript, angular, http, module, interceptor

I just upgraded my `Angular v4.2.5` app to `Angular v4.3.6` primarily to use `Interceptors`. It is quite an awesome feature and provides a clean way to intercept HTTP calls.

However, it seems I cannot scope interceptors at modules level. For example, I have an `AppModule`, and two more modules `AModule` and `BModule`. Both `AModule` and `BModule` are getting included in `AppModule`.

Now, is there a way in Angular 4 where I can scope interceptors at module level such that an interceptor I use for HTTP requests in `AModule` shouldn't be used with HTTP requests in `BModule`. Presently, interceptors are getting shared across all HTTP calls which was not I expected. I know `providers` from all modules get merged into the parent module, but is there any way to restrict such thing?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What if you have two services that extend Http and add them to the corresponding module's `providers`; `AService` to `AModule` and `BService` to `BModule`, Doesn't the service only be applied to coresponding module?

Answer (score 6):

Add a header or flag to the request from the different services? And then use this to delineate where it is from.

Comment: Yeah, appended api urls with appropriate strings and then determine in interceptor whether to take action or not based on the appended string.